# pip list and sudo pip list shows different package versions

Tags: python, macos, pip, sudo

I have a Mac, I installed Python with `Homebrew` and I installed packages with `pip`. But I found out when I call `pip list` and `sudo pip list`, it actually gives different package versions. For example, I have ipython (3.1.0) in `sudo pip list` and ipython (2.3.0) in just `pip list`. What does it mean? Do I have two both versions installed?

The reason I found out about it is because when I upgrade some of the packages, my system denied the permission, so I used `sudo`, did I do it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy: your python environment is using different paths.  do

```
$ which pip
$ sudo which pip
```

and you'll get two different paths.

Seriously consider changing over to use python virtualenv, which gets you lots better control.

Comment: Yes I got two different `pip` paths. What can I do now? How do I use `virtualenv`?

Comment: Another option would be to change your PATH setup so that you're getting the same path in both cases.

Comment: I actually find virtualenvwrapper makes life easier.  The basic idea, though, is that it lets you have lots of python environments that don't interfere with one another. https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#

Comment: Since my installation is pretty messed up, is there an easy way I can uninstall everything and start from scratch?