# pip list and sudo pip list show different package versions

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, python2.7 and pip 9.0.1

When I call `pip list` and `sudo pip list`, I get different answers.

In contrast to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607660/pip-list-and-sudo-pip-list-shows-different-package-versions) similar question, `which pip` and `sudo which pip` give the same answer: `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Note also, that `pip uninstall <packagename>` sometimes gives me `No files found to uninstall`, but then `sudo pip uninstall` does find and uninstall the packages. Packages thus uninstalled remain on the list of `pip list`, but not on `sudo pip list`. I do not know if all discrepancies between the two lists happened like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `pip list` is showing all the packages installed by current user

and `sudo pip list` is showing all the packages installed by super user

you won't be able to uninstall the package install by super user.

Comment: Note: `pip list` as a user will also show the system packages, as well as the user packages, unless in a virtualenv that excludes system packages.

Answer (score 0):

There are system packages in `/usr/[local/]lib/{site,dist}-packages/`, local (for a user) packages in `~/.local/lib` and packages in a `virtualenv`. `sudo pip` skips `virtualenv`s and runs as a different user (root), hence the difference.